# CSS: Set resize handler in the foreground and change the size

Tags: css

I've got an article with header & footer. For this article, I use `resize:both` to resize the object.
If I set the footer width to the article width, I cannot grab the "browser resize handler" anymore.
I tried it with z-index also, but to no avail.

1. Is this possible to set the "browser resize handler" to the foreground?
2. Can I change the size of the "browser resize handler"?

HTML:

```
<article class="widget">
    <header class="widget-header"  draggable="true">
        <span>Title</span>
    </header>
    <section class="widget-content">
        <span>test test test test test test test test test 
            test test test test test test test test test 
            test test test test test test test test test 
            test test test test test </span>
    </section>
    <footer class="widget-footer">
        <span>Footer</span>
    </footer>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
.widget{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 4px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    resize:both;
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    border: #000 2px solid;
    background-color: #999;
    /*.rounded-corners;*/
}

.widget-header {
    padding:2px 5px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #CCC;
    /*.header-gradient;*/
}
.widget-content {
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    bottom:23px;
    border-top: #000 solid 2px;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
.widget-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:2px 5px;

}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/J4bq7/)
Try to grab the resize handler in the example... This is not possible.

Comment: Could you add some code? It would help clarify your problem, and what you want to have happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding the property [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) to your footer, which will indicate that the element will never be the target of mouse events.

Here's [the updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/J4bq7/9/):

```css
.widget-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:2px 5px;

    /* New styles below: */

    pointer-events: none;
}
```

As for changing the display of the resize handle, that can't be done in CSS alone. When using something like jQuery UI to manage resizing elements, you can apply a different handle, but the default handle is browser- and OS-based, and currently can't be changed.

#### Note:

The drawback of this method is that the footer text can only be selected when you select an area before and after the footer. To work around this, you can just change the footer's `right` property to be ~10px, if you don't need it to have a background color/image, to make it not overlap with the resize handle at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this.

```
<article class="widget" style="min-width:200px;
min-height:80px;">
```

then take out the min-width and min-height out of your css file.

```
.widget{
position: absolute;
margin: 4px;
top:0;
left:0;
width:300px;
resize:both !important;
overflow: auto;

cursor:pointer;
border: #000 2px solid;
background-color: #999;
}
```