# CSS resize handle "z-index"

Tags: css, canvas

I'm trying to do a resizable canvas element using CSS `resize`. The setup looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="canvas-wrapper">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.canvas-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.canvas-wrapper canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

It works just fine **but** the resize handle is always hidden by the canvas. I surely could add an additional child element with the `resize` property to the wrapper and place it above the canvas but this seems rather inelegant.

Now is there any way to influence the "z-index" of the resize handle?

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240225/css-set-resize-handler-in-the-foreground-and-change-the-size) question but they do a workaround there, too.

**Edit**: It seems that the handle remains usable in some browsers even if its hidden by the canvas (try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rPfHQ/)). Probably the spec isn't very accurate on this behaviour. Does anyone have further information about this?

Comment: Working for me fine in Chrome and Firefox. It's not supported in any IE version.

Comment: @gaynorvader Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rPfHQ/). Can you grab the handle?

Comment: Yes, although the cursor doesn't change.

Comment: Strange. In Firefox, too?

Comment: In Firefox, the cursor changes and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems there is no solution without a little workaround I finally used the `pointer-events: none` property mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240225/css-set-resize-handler-in-the-foreground-and-change-the-size?lq=1). This enables the resize handler (at least for me in Firefox and Chrome) no matter if it is behind the canvas or not.

For visual feedback I used a pseudo-element. See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rPfHQ/5/) for how it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

i changed it a bit in this i think this is what you were trying to accomplish

http://jsfiddle.net/aidan2129/U7J9k/

```
.canvas-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.canvas-wrapper2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}


.canvas-wrapper canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;    
  background-color:blue;
}

.canvas-wrapper2 canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;    
  background-color:red;
}
```

It seems to work fine i have just set the position to absolute so it does not take the full length of the page but if you resize the result canvas element to the right you will see the blue canvas appear behind the red one.

Hope this helps

Comment: This works for you? For me it is the same as in my fiddle. I think this is an issue of my Firefox (27 on Linux) since that one worked for gaynorvader, too.

Comment: yeah it must be sorry if that wasn't much help i hope you find a solution